# AMD GPU Overheating and Shutting Down after 5.15.15 Kernel Update (Pop!_OS 21.10)

Tags: linux-kernel, pop-os, mesa, amdgpu

I am new to the forums here, but I have a question regarding some unusual issues I have encountered after a recent system update on my installation. After upgrading to Kernel 5.15.15 (or possibly the latest Mesa drivers -- 21.3.6) I have encountered an issue where, when placed under load, my GPU is reaching its emergency junction temperature (115C) causing a system shutdown without warning.

```
Feb 11 23:02:23 pop-os kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ERROR: GPU over temperature range(SW CTF) detected!
Feb 11 23:02:23 pop-os kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ERROR: System is going to shutdown due to GPU SW CTF!
```

The full systemd/journald log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/HMqXp3BN) with the amdgpu error appearing around line 256, after which all logs denote the shutdown process.

Now, normally, I believe the system should throttle the GPU before it reaches this temperature, but I could be mistaken. In any case, this issue appears to be new, as running the system under identical circumstances with the old kernel (5.13) and Mesa driver (unfortunately, I do not know the previous version number) never resulted in a system shutdown, nor does the GPU cause problems when running under Windows. But since the recent round of system updates, I have experienced this issue three times in a span of 24 hours.

For context, my system is as follows:

- OS: Pop!_OS 21.10 x86_64
- Kernel Version: 5.15.15-76051515-generic #202201160435~1642693824~21.10~97db1bb
- GPU 1: AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT
- GPU 2: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 Ti (unused on Linux, and there are no drivers installed)
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X

Does anyone know if this is a known issue, or perhaps something that can be worked around? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will post this issue there, as well.